# Test cases are failing vstest.console.exe in docker windows console with https

Tags: c#, .net, windows, powershell, docker

I am running API-test using restsharp with Nunit and test cases are failing with `vstest.console.exe` in docker windows, getting "0" as a response. While passing on the local system.

I am hitting the https application from the docker container.

It is because of the SSL certificate, I verified with HTTP request it is working as expected.

To verify the connection I used

```
invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing https://hostname
```

and getting this error in container

> invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

When I am using `invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing http://hostname` I am getting 200 StatusCode.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not with vstest.console.exe. This issue is because of SSL/TLS. The container was not able to make an https connection with my application because of CA(Certificate Authority).

When I import CA to my container everything is working as expected. To import certificate I used PowerShell command

```
Import-Certificate -FilePath "file.cer" -CertStoreLocation Cert:\\LocalMachine\\Root
```